# gtk filechooser with msys2 return not correct values

Tags: c, windows, gtk, msys2

in my project i compiled a gtk-gui with msys2. I think everything works fine except for one thing.
If i start my application and try to choose a file with the filechooser i recognized that in the first attempt the return value of the
`gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder()` is NULL. In the second try the return value seems to be correct but the last folder is missing.
Compiling and running it under linux leads to no problem. I use glade in combination with gtk.

I'm not sure what kind of code snipped i should post here, but if you want to see a specific thing i will upload it of course.

I would be very pleased about some suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first i initialize the FileChooserWidget:

```
WCO_GUI_Ref()->MyFileChosserButton1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(WCO_GUI_Ref()->MyBuilder, "MyFileChosserButton1"));
```

If you choose a folder with the FileChooser a function is called which stores the return value and print it out:

```
WCO_PDF_SetFoldername(WCO_ENTRY(WCO_GUI_Get(folder_name)));
```

The `WCO_GUI_Get()` function returns a void pointer which is casted by the `WCO_ENTRY()` macro. In this function the i call `gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder()` like this:

```bash
void *WCO_GUI_Get(int id)
{
  void *ret;
  
  switch(id)
  {
    case 0: ret = gtk_file_chooser_get_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(WCO_GUI_Ref()->MyFileChosserButton1)); break;
    default: break;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

If i place this debug code:

```
printf("%s", WCO_ENTRY(WCO_GUI_Get(folder_name)) );
```

The Output of it in the first try is `(null)` and after the first one i got a output like this `C:\usr\documents\` but the actual selected folder is `C:\usr\documents\test\`